# JavaScript - Array newLength from MDN tutorial

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working through a tutorial on Arrays from MDN and I can't understand HOW the code line "newLength" is returning the value of 7? I understand that there are 7 items in the array but **how is it doing it** when there is no ".length" on the end.

---

My Code -

```
var myData = 'Manchester,London,Liverpool,Birmingham,Leeds,Carlisle';

var myArray = myData.split(',');

var newLength = myArray.push('Bristol');

console.log(myArray);

console.log(newLength);
```

---

This is the return result within console -

```
[ 'Manchester',

  'London',

  'Liverpool',

  'Birmingham',

  'Leeds',

  'Carlisle',

  'Bristol' ]

7
```

---

Thx for your help!

Comment: See the docs. `myArray.push()` returns the length. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: From [the page I assume you're on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays), right before it does that line of code: _"The new length of the array is returned when the method call completes. If you wanted to store the new array length in a variable, you could do something like this"_  Don't just read the code in a tutorial, read the tutorial itself too.

Comment: James Thorpe... Thank you for the quick reply, I am reading through the tutorial and not just simply copying the code.

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.push() returns the new length of the array you pushed on: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

it's quite simple... 
The function push returns the new length of your array.

```
var newLength = myArray.push('Bristol'); //Returns the new length
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

bro, push method returns length of the array after pushed the content so thats the reason you get 7.
first push the element and then store that in newarray field like this.

Var myData ='Manchester,London,Liverpool,Birmingham,Leeds,Carlisle';

var myArray = myData.split(',');

myArray.push('Bristol');
var newLength = myArray;

console.log(myArray);

console.log(newLength);